# AWS Cognito Pre Authentication Lambda Trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(event));
    // TODO implement
    
    return callback(null, event);
};
```

I just trying to print the event content. But it is empty (it just logs the START requestID and End requestID (no info about event) when I look into the cloudwatch logs. what am I doing wrong ?

I also increased the timeout to 10s based on some of the response to similar question on stackoverflow

Resource summary

Resource    Actions
arn:aws:logs:us-east-2:xx:*

```
Allow: logs:CreateLogGroup
```

arn:aws:logs:us-east-2:xx:log-group:/aws/lambda/signoutUserFromAllSessions:*

```
Allow: logs:CreateLogStream
Allow: logs:PutLogEvents
```

Lambda obtained this information from the following policy statements:

```
Managed policy AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole-8f2866cf-1300-4844-a2de-834c34274555, statement 0
Managed policy AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole-8f2866cf-1300-4844-a2de-834c34274555, statement 1
```

Log from CLOUDWATCH

2021-11-24T10:45:40.978-05:00

START RequestId: a3fab381-9029-4583-99ac-e21464bf915c Version: $LATEST
START RequestId: a3fab381-9029-4583-99ac-e21464bf915c Version: $LATEST
2021-11-24T10:45:40.993-05:00

END RequestId: a3fab381-9029-4583-99ac-e21464bf915c
END RequestId: a3fab381-9029-4583-99ac-e21464bf915c
2021-11-24T10:45:40.993-05:00

REPORT RequestId: a3fab381-9029-4583-99ac-e21464bf915c  Duration: 13.22 ms  Billed Duration: 14 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 56 MB  Init Duration: 160.71 ms

```
REPORT RequestId: a3fab381-9029-4583-99ac-e21464bf915c Duration: 13.22 ms Billed Duration: 14 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 56 MB Init Duration: 160.71 ms
```

UPDATES

1. You must deploy the code after making any changes. I was under the impression that saving the code in the web console is good enough.

Comment: What do you mean by empty?  If there's nothing being logged at all, you'll need to configure the Lambda to have permissions to write to CloudWatch.  Assigning the AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole to the Lambda should do it.

Comment: it has those permissions. I updated my original question with the info. By empty, I meant no info about event is logged. It just says START with requestID and END with requestID. Followed by Report of billing

Comment: I would suggest you try logging some static test output to validate.  In theory, console.log with the appropriate permissions against the Lambda should work.